# python 3 send email

Tags: python-3.x, email, jenkins

i want to send email from a gmail/yahoo account to another gmail/yahoo account. For that i have setup a jenkins job where this python script runs:

```
 def sendMail(self):

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        password = '******'

        server.starttls()
        server.login('****@gmail.com', password)
        server.sendmail('****@gmail.com', ['****@email.com'], self.mailBody)
        server.quit()
```

there exist some other codes before given block of code , other codes run fine but i face timeout error in this line

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being Captain Obvious. Are you 100% sure that `smtp.gmail.com:587` is reachable from your jenkins host? Try telnet to check.

Comment: if it needs to be triggered then pretty good chance that it was not, new to this, can you please help with that?

Comment: In bash: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` You should see 220 (Service ready) code.

Comment: BTW your problem has nothing with django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
 def sendMail(self):
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        password = '******'
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login('****@gmail.com', password)
        server.sendmail('****@gmail.com', ['****@email.com'], self.mailBody)
        server.quit()
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, feel free to set my answer as verified, and thank you !